# How to use VBA ADO recordset.Supports(adDelete) with late binding?

Tags: vba, ado, recordset

For constants like LockType I use Enum.
E.g.:

```
   Enum eLockType
       adLockUnspecified = -1
       adLockReadOnly = 1
       adLockPessimistic = 2
       adLockOptimistic = 3
       adLockBatchOptimistic = 4
   End Enum
```

However, this doesn't work with `adDelete = 0x1000800`.
I've tried `adDelete = 16779264` or `adDelete = Hex(16779264)` which didn't work either.
Is there any solution on how adDelete can be declared for late binding or any other solution how  `recordset.Supports(adDelete)` can be used with late binding?

Comment: Try `adDelete = &H1000800`

Comment: This one does the trick!!! Many, many thanks!